# Render JSON object name in Jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

I have a JSON:

```
{
  "providers" : {
    "visa" : {
      "name" : "VISA",
      "type" : "card",
      "enabled" : true,
    },
    "qiwi" : {
      "name" : "QIWI",
      "type" : "digital",
      "enabled" : true,
    },
    …
  }
}
```

I can render this and get `name`, `type`, `enabled`.

```
-each item in providers
    tr
        td enabled: #{item.enabled}
        td name: #{item.name}
        td type: #{item.type}
        td id: ???
```

But how can I get object names – “visa” or “qiwi” – in template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;

```
  -each item, key in providers
    tr
      td enabled: #{item.enabled}
      td name: #{item.name}
      td type: #{item.type}
      td id: #{key}
```